# How to Change Icon name when pressed in react native vector icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-native-vector-icons

I'm using react-native-vector-icons

And I want to change the name of an icon at first time the screen load I can see the icon very well but when pressed it doesn't work anymore and I see question mark **?**

```
this.state={
favIcon:"heart-empty"
}
 <Icon name={`ios-${favIcon}`} style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} size={30} color="#fff" onPress={() => this.setState({ favIcon: "heart" }, alert(favIcon))} />
```

any Idea to handle name to accept a variable?

and when I log the `this.state.FavIcon` it's **undefined** !!

--

### nevermind it's work now :D, I'm just editing the name of an icon when setState, and rename the name of the state

now the new Q is 
when I pressed the icon I change the icon into "ios-heart", now if I want to press again I want to change to "ios-heart-empty"

the idea of function I wanna do is Add to Favorite and Remove from Favorite

Comment: you are setting state with `favIcon` and using state as `FavIcon`. Can you please elaborate it more clearly?

Comment: it's a bit confuse, is the variable name FavIcon or favIcon? if you set favIcon and try to log FavIcon, it will be indefined

Comment: Yup, I just do that, can you check the question again

Answer (score 1):

You can do something as follow:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)

   this.state={ 
      providerId: '',
      providerName: '',
      providerService: '',
      fav: false
   } 

   this.ref = firebase.database().ref(`favorites/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}`);
}
```

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._onFavourite = this.ref.on('child_added', () => {
        this.setState({
            fav: true
        }, alert("Added To Favorite List"))
    })
    this._onUnFavourite = this.ref.on('child_removed', () => {
        this.setState({
            fav: false
        }, alert("Removed from Favorite List"))
    })
}
```

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this._onFavourite) {
        this.ref.off('child_added', this._onFavourite);
    }
    if (this._onUnFavourite) {
        this.ref.off('child_removed', this._onUnFavourite);
    }
}
```

```
_favOrUnFav = () => {
    if (!this.state.fav){ 
        const { 
            providerId,
            providerName,
            providerService
        } = this.state;

        this.ref.set({
            providerId,
            providerName,
            providerService
        })
    } else ref.set(null)  OR you can use ref.remove()
}
```

```
const {
     fav
} = this.state

<Icon 
    name={`ios-heart${fav ? "" : "-empty"}`}
    style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} 
    size={30} 
    color="#fff" 
    onPress={this._favOrUnFav} 
/>
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's work very well, But I have some little issue I need when i go to user profile i want to see the Fav icon it's "ios-heart" that's mean it's in the favorite list but when I go to the user profile I see just "ios-heart-empty" but the user is already in favorite list by the way, how to handle these

Answer (score 0):

`onPress` is only available on `Icon.Button`, not `Icon`. See https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#iconbutton-component for more information about `Icon.Button`.